# Can't create schema extension in microsoft graph

Tags: azure, rust, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create a schema extension but I get the following error message every time I make a request:

code: 400, error_message: ErrorMessage { error: Some(ErrorStatus { code: Some("Request_BadRequest"), message: Some("Object of class ComplexExtensionDefinition is not valid for Megatenant with ContextId: 11753285-9b24-41e2-bef1-********. Update to segmentation metadata failed.")

According to the error message seems like I cant extend azure AD with schema extension. Any help ?

Thanks

Here's the code for reference:

```
use graph_rs_sdk::oauth::OAuth;
use reqwest::StatusCode;
use graph_rs_sdk::prelude::*;
use graph_rs_sdk::error::GraphFailure;

pub async fn account_ext(client: OAuth) -> Result<StatusCode, GraphFailure> {
    let graph_client = Graph::new_async(client.get_access_token().unwrap().bearer_token());

    let properties = serde_json::json!({
        "id": "tenantaccountExt",
        "description": "Tenant account extension properties",
        "targetTypes": [
            "Group"
        ],
        "owner": "90fd44ac-18d2-4920-909b-********",
        "properties": [
            {
                "name": "region",
                "type": "String"
            },
            {
                "name": "contact",
                "type": "String"
            },
        ]
    });

    match graph_client.v1()
        .schema_extensions()
        .create_schema_extension(&properties)
        .send()
        .await {
            Ok(response) => Ok(response.status()),
            Err(GraphFailure::GraphError(err)) => {
                println!("{:?}", err);
                Ok(err.code)
            },
            Err(err) => Err(err)
        }
}
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @PitaJ I have added the code for reference.

Comment: I have the azure AD free license. Does this have to do anything with me not being able to create schemaExtensions ?

Comment: For creating Schema Extension using the graph explorer please refer to the this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/schemaextension-post-schemaextensions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-1-creating-a-schema-extension-using-a-verified-domain

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar sort of error towards application :

```
"code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Attempt to update complex extension definition on application: xxxxxx belonging to different context",
```

with below query

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions

{
    "id": "tenantcountext",
    "description": "Graph Learn training courses extensions",
    "targetTypes": [
        "group"
    ],
    "owner": "dexxxxxxxxxxx64",
    "properties": [
        {
            "name": "region",
            "type": "String"
        },
        {
            "name": "contact",
            "type": "String"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

- The id property must be unique string  of the schema extension
  definition. {domainName}_{schemaName}  or echemaName only.
- When I tried to check for available extension schema definitions for
  id : tenantaccountExt :[Add custom data to groups using schema
  extensions - Microsoft Graph | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-schema-groups#1-view-available-schema-extensions).

I could not find any `available` status for that id which may mean  that tenant has one or more applications that doesn’t have the owner permissions to add or update extensions or any changes or even the tenant doen not have proper ***permissions*** .( For me when I checked the appId in the error in azureAd apps , it is the Microsoft graph explorer)

[image]

which means the tenant or apps do not have proper permissions to access graph explorer or do any creation or updates .

- So please check if that app or tenant in your case has proper
  permissions to add any changes or extensions like
  ***`Applications.ReadWrite.All, User.Read.All, User.ReadWrite.All,Group.ReadWrite.All microsoft graph permissions`***.Please try to get permissions given by admin and
  check to try again.
- Also check to have ,Any of the following permissions: for

> **Delegated  (work or school account)** check ***`Directory.Read.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All, Directory.AccessAsUser.All`***
>
> **Application**: ***`Directory.Read.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All`***

Importantly please make sure , ***the owner property must be having the value of the application Id where you are the owner i.e; you must be the owner of the app for which extension is done*** and  request for creation must also be coming from that application.

---

[image]

---

If everything is correct, then then the schema extension is executed and we can get its available status like InDevelopment or available.

[image]

**Reference**: [exercise-schema-extensions | microsoftDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msgraph-extensions/7-exercise-schema-extensions)

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. Seems like I have been doing everything as you said. My app has all the permissions but I haven't looked into tenant permissions. When you say tenant permissions, it doesn't mean app right ? I can see the permissions for my app, but where can I see tenant permissions ?